# Typo in Help Center > Our model > What is meta?

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, help-center

There is a typo (marked bold) on the [*"What is "meta"? How does it work?"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) page of Meta Stack Exchange in the very first sentence:

> Meta Stack Exchange is the part of the site where users discuss the
>   workings and policies of Stack Overflow the company and the software
>   **the** runs the Stack Exchange Q&A network.

If I'm not completely confused right now *"the"* should be replaced with *"that"* or *"which"*.

This, to my knowledge, only occurs on Meta Stack Exchange, since the opening sentences are different on other meta sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.

That template has been corrected.